# put top 2 biggest keys and values of dictionary in another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Here is my dictionary:

```
d = {'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'c': 300, 'd': 350}
```

I can find top 2 keys with biggest values and put them to the list:

```
sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True)[:2]
```

But what should I do to put top 2 biggest keys and values in another dictionary instead of list?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Sort `dict.items` based on values.
2. Slice the sorted list.
3. Pass the sliced list to `dict()`.
4. Pass the dict returned from `dict()` to `update` method of the dict you want to modify.

**Demo:**

```
>>> d = {'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'c': 300, 'd': 350}
>>> dic = {}
>>> dic.update(dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)[:2]))
>>> dic
{'c': 300, 'd': 350}
```

Using `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
dic = {}
dic.update(dict(sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:2]))
```

If dictionary is huge then [`heapq.nlargest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) will be more efficient than `sorted`:

```
>>> import heapq
>>> dic = {}
>>> dic.update({k:d[k] for k in heapq.nlargest(2, d, key=d.get)})
>>> dic
{'c': 300, 'd': 350}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the lambda?

Comment: @user2799617  what's up? lambda is really good for this situation.Or you write a version without lambda and more efficient?

Comment: hey `dic = dict(sorted(d.items(), key = lambda a: a[1], reverse = True)[:2])` was enough any specific reason to use `dic.update()` function?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan OP wanted to update an already existing dictionary, so used `dict.update`.

Answer (score 1):

```
dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)[:2])
```

update something:

thanks for the one upvotes.

I saw no one answered this question so I decided to answer it,but when I submitted my answer ,it already ranked 3rd.

I am glab to see the VERY USEFUL form "lambda x:x[1]" showed up in the earlist answer.

I strongly recommend this form.Simple yet Powerful in descripting idea.

I also strongly wonder: the one downvote the lambda form-what's up with lambda? any better idea to share with us?